# tableview cell checkmark disable when scroll

Tags: iphone

when i scroll the tabview cell ,then the checkmark is hidden.what i do?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setSelected:NO];

    FacebookFriend *friend = [self.fbFriendsFiltered objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Build list to invite
    if ( [self.fbFriendsInvited containsObject:friend.fid] ) {
        [self.fbFriendsInvited removeObject:friend.fid];
        NSLog(@"fbFriendsInvited:%@",self.fbFriendsInvited);
        [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    } else {
        //if ( [self.fbFriendsInvited count] >= kSelectionLimit )
          //  return;

        [self.fbFriendsInvited addObject:friend.fid];
        [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
        NSLog(@"fbFriendsInvited:%@",self.fbFriendsInvited);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a conditional check in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to set the checkmark for any cell that was previously checked. Keep an array/set of `NSIndexPath`s of selected cells and check against it.

Comment: How about you try to implement it yourself and after that you can ask for more help, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to add following code in cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
NSArray *array = [cell subviews];
for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++)
{
    if([[array objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
        [[array objectAtIndex:i] removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

**after** -

```
 if (cell == nil) 
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}
```